# Is it possible to find the derivative of $y = 2^x$ using Calculus Made Easy-style infinitesimals?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, infinitesimals

I was wondering today...

Is it possible to find $dy/dx$ given $y=2^x$ using infinitesimals of the sort found in Thompson's Calculus Made Easy?

For example, Thompson found the derivative of $x^2$ by letting $y+dy=(x+dx)^2$ and doing some algebra (plus letting some higher order differentials "vanish").

I tried to do something similar with my exponential function:

$y+dy=2^{x+dx}$

But I got stuck, and now I am not even sure it is possible to differentiate $2^x$ using this strategy. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is using the power series for the exponential in the proof fair game? If so, I feel like user48672's answer here might prove a little helpful with manipulation (though I'm just guessing) -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578260/non-standard-analysis-way-of-proving-that-derivative-of-ex-is-ex

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I'd *prefer* not to have to use any power series, since we actually haven't covered that in my class yet... :)

Comment: Well, next step is $y+dy = 2^x*2^{dx}$ and it's just a matter of showing $2^{dx} = \ln 2 = \int_{1}^2 \frac {dx}x$ which.... is the infinite sum?  $dx(\frac 11 + \frac 1{1+dx} + .... + \frac 1{2-dx} + \frac 12$ )?  [I've always hated this part....]

Comment: @fleablood I haven't learned integrals yet, alas!

Comment: I don't think you can finish yet.  But I do think that with his "easy" method it will probably work.  Eventually.  But to find the derivative of $b^x$ by any method you get that it is $b^x\cdot Ln(b)$ where $Ln$ is some function $(0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$.  [Spoiler alert $Ln(b) = \ln b$.]  But to get that part takes extra info and at least knowing what a *anti-derivative* is.

Comment: I'm curious now.  $y + dy = 2^{x+dx} = 2^x 2^{dx}$ so $dy = 2^x(2^{dx} - 1)$ and $\frac {dy}{dx} = 2^x\frac{2^{dx}-1}{dx}$.  Now suppose $F(x)$ is a function so that $F(1)=0$ and $\frac {dF(x)}{dx} = \frac 1x$.  Can we manipulate that somehow $F(2)=\frac {2^{dx}-1}{dx}$?  I''m not sure I'm familiar enough with these "easy" calculus to properly manipulate that.  But if I could, that would be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to all of this is the number $L(a) = (a^{dx}-1)/dx$. This is a new sort of function, not expressible as a rationally in terms of $a$. The crucial fact is that

## $L$ is a logarithm

I say that $L$ is a logarithm, which requires proving that
$$ L(ab) = L(a) + L(b) \tag{1} $$
for $a,b>0$.
But
$$ L(ab) dx = a^{dx} b^{dx} - 1 = (1+L(a)dx)(1+L(a)dx) - 1 = (L(a)+L(b))dx $$
since $a^{dx} = 1 + L(a)dx $, and dividing by $dx$ gives the result. $(1)$ gives us a lot of information about $L$:
$$ L(a) = L(a \cdot 1) = L(a) + L(1) , $$
so $L(1)=0$, $0 = L(a/a) = L(a) + L(1/a) $, so $L(1/a)=-L(a)$, and
$$ L(a^n) = L(aa^{n-1}) = L(a) + L(a^{n-1}) = \dotsb = n L(a), \tag{2} $$
and eventually for any $b$,
$$ L(a^b) = bL(a) . $$

## Derivative?

Which logarithm is it? Let's start with a seemingly more difficult question: what is the derivative of $L$?
$$ L(x+dx) = L(x(1+dx/x)) = L(x) + L(1+dx/x) = L(1) + L'(1) dx/x = L(x) + L'(1) dx/x $$
This is reasonably uncontroversial. The hairy part: what is $L'(1)$?
$$ L(x+dx) dy = (x+dx)^{dy}-1 = x^{dy}\left(1+\frac{dx}{x}\right)^{dy}-1 = (1+L(x)dy)\left(1+\frac{dx}{x}dy\right) -1 = \left(L(x) + \frac{dx}{x} \right) dy . $$
So this very suspicious manipulation gives $L'(x) = 1/x$. Hence $L$ is increasing, and in particular, $L(2)>0$, and for any positive $a,b$, 
$$L(a)=L(b) \implies L(a/b)=0 \quad \text{, so } a=b. $$ 
Moreover, $(2)$ implies that $L(x)$ is unbounded above as $x \to \infty$, unbounded below as $x \to 0$. Now we can ask

## Which logarithm?

In particular, there is some number $E$ so that $L(E)=1$. But this means that
$$ L(E^x) = xL(E) = x, $$
for any real $x$. We can write $x=L(y)$, and then
$$ L(E^{L(y)}) = L(y) , $$
and so $(3)$ implies that
$$ E^{L(y)} = y , $$
for any positive $y$. So $E^x$ and $L(x)$ are inverse functions. We also have $E^{aL(y)} = E^{L(y^a)} = y^a$.

Wrapping up, $E^{dx} = 1 + L(E)dx = 1 + dx$, so $ (E^{dx}-1)/dx = 1 $, and using the definition $e = (1+dx)^{1/dx}$ (substituting the limit involving $n$ for a simple infinitesimal expression),
$$ L(e) = L((1+dx)^{1/dx}) = \frac{L(1+dx)}{dx} = \frac{L(1)+L'(1)dx}{dx} = L'(1) = 1 , $$
so $E=e$, and $L = \log$, pretty much whatever your definitions are.

---

## Post mortem

Now, there are numerous problems with the above derivation: we haven't said how to define arbitrary real powers, but have used them liberally. The suspicious bit is some sort of nasty double limit that we'd be better off staying well clear of. Inverse functions have been used fairly glibly throughout. But most of this can actually be made rigorous!

Comment: Wow... So I guess this problem can be solved using infinitesimals, but it's *way* more complicated than differentiating, say, y = x^2.

Comment: So, to clarify: $ln(a) = (a^{b}-1)/b$? If true, wow.

Comment: Yes: this is certainly not an easy way to introduce logarithms! Polynomials are easy to differentiate because of the binomial theorem: the process is essentially just algebra. Even defining the general real power in the first place is way more difficult, and requires some sort of limiting process. The usual approach introduces the exponential and logarithm in some other way, and then the derivatives fall out of $e^{x\log{a}}$, with the chain rule for the derivative with respect to $a$.

Comment: Not quite. To be completely precise, for $a>0$,
$$ \log{a} = \lim_{n \to \infty} n(a^{1/n}-1) , $$
which can be defined using only $n$th roots. You may recognise this from "reverse-engineering $e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+x/n)^n$:
$$ y = (1+x/n)^n \implies x=n(y^{1/n}-1). $$

Comment: Wait what?? :) You get the same dy/dx ratio if you just use the expression I wrote though, right? Is that just coincidence?

Comment: The point is that $dx$ is infinitesimal: $ (a^{dx}-1)/dx = \log{a} $ because the higher-order terms in the series vanish ($dx^2=0$). This is not true for non-infinitesimals. The expression involving infinitesimals translates to
$$ \log{a} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} , $$
which is not the same as $(a^h-1)/h$ for some small, but finite and nonzero, $h$.

Comment: Ah, excellent, makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Just because I amazed that it works, I will post for now using the power series (or actually just using Taylor polynome!) :

$$
2^{dx} = e^{dxln(2)} = 1 + \ln(2)dx + O((\ln(2)dx)^2) = 1 + \ln(2)dx,
$$
where $O(x^n)$ is the $O$ notation, that means all the terms are of order $n$ or higher.

So you actually get:
$$
y + dy = 2^x + \ln(2)dx2^x
$$

**edit** 
Maybe using Pascal triangle or the binomial theorem it sounds reasonable to you that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(1+\frac{y}{n}\right)^n = 1 + n \frac{y}{n} + \binom{n}{2}\frac{y^2}{n^2} +\dots
\end{aligned}
$$
so again you can infer
$$
e^{\ln(2)dx} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{\ln(2)dx}{n} \right)^n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1 + \ln(2)dx + O\left(\frac{dx^2}{n^2}\right)\right) = 1 +\ln(2)dx
$$

Comment: Wait doesn't your answer $y + dy = 2^x + \ln(2)dx$ imply that $dy/dx=ln(2)$? Shouldn't the derivative be $2^x*ln(2)$?

Comment: Thanks edited it :).

Comment: Cool. I'll admit I don't really understand your answer (as I said in the comment, I don't know power series!) but it does seem pretty nifty.

Comment: Mh, may I asked what definition of $e$, you are using?

Comment: The continuously compounding interest/limit definition is what I learned in Pre-Calc last year.

Comment: So that ist $e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n$?

Comment: @Will I added a way to see it with that definition as well. Thanks for this cool "horrific" trick. Though, I actually think that this method can be made rigorous.